# is early exit of loops on GPU worth doing?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader, gpu

We've written GLSL shader code to do ray tracing visualisation using the GPU. It seems to be pretty standard to put an early exit break in the ray marching loop, so if the light is extinguished, the loop breaks.

But from what I know about GPU code, each render will take as long as the longest loop run. So my question is: is it worth the early exit?

e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS; i++){
        //Get the voxel intensity value from the 3D texture.    
        dataRGBA = getRGBAfromDataTex(dataTexture, currentPosition, dataShape, textureShape);

        // get contribution from the light
        lightRayPathRGBA = getPathRGBA(currentPosition, light.position, steps, tex); // this is the light absorbed so we need to take 1.0- to get the light transmitted
        lightRayRGBA = (vec4(1.0) - lightRayPathRGBA) * vec4(light.color, light.intensity);

        apparentRGB = (1.0 - accumulatedAlpha) * dataRGBA.rgb * lightRayRGBA.rgb * dataRGBA.a * lightRayRGBA.a;
        //apparentRGB = (1.0 - accumulatedAlpha) * dataRGBA.rgb * dataRGBA.a * lightRayRGBA.a;

        //Perform the composition.
        accumulatedColor += apparentRGB;
        //Store the alpha accumulated so far.
        accumulatedAlpha += dataRGBA.a;

        //Adva      nce the ray.
        currentPosition += deltaDirection;
        accumulatedLength += deltaDirectionLength;

        //If the length traversed is more than the ray length, or if the alpha accumulated reaches 1.0 then exit.
        if(accumulatedLength >= rayLength || accumulatedAlpha >= 1.0 ){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The scheduling unit of GPUs is the warp / wavefront. Usually that's consecutive groups of 32 or 64 threads. The execution time of a warp is the maximum of the execution time of all threads within that warp.

So if your early exit can make a whole warp terminate sooner (for example, if threads 0 to 31 *all* take the early exit), then yes, it is worth it, because the hardware can schedule another warp to execute and that reduces the overall kernel run time. Otherwise, it probably isn't, because even if threads 1 to 31 take the early exit, the warp still occupies the hardware until thread 0 is done.

Comment: I'm not 100% what that means - probably need a google. Basically, its a start trek thing, right?

Oh no, probably not.

So, if the slowest of 32/64 threads is still exiting early, then it will help, but if not, it wont?

But...as I understand, if statements slow GPU code down as well. So is it worth not having the exit early, if it means one fewer if statements?

Comment: `if` statements don't slow down your code, divergent branches within warps do (when threads within the same warp do not evaluate a branch predicate identically). An early exit has 0 performance impact in the sense that it doesn't slow down the rest of your code: threads that take the early exit simply get disabled.

Comment: @nrob: Perfect answer and comment by Cicada. Essentially it boils down, that the GPU will process pixels in blocks (warp / wavefront) of n×m fragments (n and m varying by GPU, but usually both between 8 and 32 with current hardware). The program flow will be the same for every fragment in that block and in the case of divergence within a warp/wavefront either path will be taken. So if only one fragment in a warp/wavefront terminates early, you earn very little. But if you can make the whole warp/wavefront terminate early, you free up GPU cores and cycles.

Comment: @nrob: On a side note: One of the first things people do when learning GPU atomic counters is visualizing the rasterization pattern (i.e. how the GPU schedules fragments into warps/wavefronts). See this article: http://www.geeks3d.com/20120309/opengl-4-2-atomic-counter-demo-rendering-order-of-fragments/

Comment: Thanks everyone - that's helped.